# How to start explorer if Ctrl + Alt + Delete and Windows commands do not work?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, kaspersky

first, thank you for browsig the entry.

I will save a lot of text by sayin: i messed up.

I installed boom3d in my pc and it worked fine until KS total security 2020 began trowing notifications about the boom app trying to copy a process id  I noticed that the task in particular was explorer after changibg the view of the app manager that comes with ks i noticed explorer had started a few other programs and boom3d had had severalsuspisious activitiesapproved

I made the mistake of blockin explorer from starting in Ksts

Wen i boot my laptop it goes well until i enter my credentials (i have my windows id linked to the laptop) then i can only see my mouse if i try control alt delete i get an error notification window: failure to dysplay security and shutdown options.

Windows r doesent work either. I have atempted to do a format but the pc doesent start from the dvd drive and it doesent get acces to the boot drive anymore or hdd :/
But nevertheless i will try with a USB see whatbhappens

Comment: Nuke the machine. Reinstall. Simple as that.

Comment: Hello, dave. Nothing would make me happier but after habing made the pc boot in safe mode i thougjt i could avoid the issue by disabling laspersky from starting with windows boy o boy was I wrong i think il have to use my phone as a  Usb hopefully thay works since the system does not want to boot from my dvd tray

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: Am I the only one here to shudder when someone says "Hello, Dave..."?

Comment: Try in safe mode: press and hold the Shift key while you select the Power > Restart on the logon screen. And see if you can remove explorer from the block-list there.